# How to artemis queue from command line?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there any way to purger artemis queues? I have already purged then by going `cd data/paging`. This is the location where I have installed my artemis broker.

There is a UI called `haw.io` of artemis , though I Have deleted all the files in the paging directory, it sill shows the message on the UI, which in the correct case should not be there.

Please suggest.

Comment: It is unclear what you have done, but the ActiveMQ docs list all the ways you can purge a queue. None of them involve deleting files or directories, BTW. If this is what you have done, I'm not in the least surprised that the UI is confused.

Answer (score 5):

From command line in your broker instance bin folder:

```
artemis queue delete --user user --password password --name queue-name
```

Answer (score 3):

Artemis Broker provides a REST management API that users can use to read and change many of the broker's parameters in run time. Therefore, it's possible to purge a queue from command line using a command line like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d  '{ "type": "EXEC", "mbean": "org.apache.activemq.artemis:address=\"test.performance.queue\",broker=\"0.0.0.0\",component=addresses,queue=\"test.performance.queue\",routing-type=\"anycast\",subcomponent=queues", "operation": "removeMessages(java.lang.String)", "arguments": [ "" ] }' http://localhost:8161/jolokia/exec | jq .
```

In this example above, I am purging the contents of a queue named `test.performance.queue` on a broker instance `0.0.0.0`. These parameters need to be adjusted for the specific case.

Obs: note that I used `jq .` simply to make the response JSON prettier (you don't need to do that if you don't care about the response):

```
{
  "request": {
    "mbean": "org.apache.activemq.artemis:address=\"test.performance.queue\",broker=\"0.0.0.0\",component=addresses,queue=\"test.performance.queue\",routing-type=\"anycast\",subcomponent=queues",
    "arguments": [
      ""
    ],
    "type": "exec",
    "operation": "removeMessages(java.lang.String)"
  },
  "value": 13001,
  "timestamp": 1503740691,
  "status": 200
}
```

Another possibility, might be to use the [BMIC](https://github.com/orpiske/bmic) tool, which provides access to several APIs used for managing ActiveMQ 6 and Artemis brokers (disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the tool). Using that, you can do the same thing using this command:

```
./bmic queue -u admin -p admin -s localhost --name test.performance.queue --purge
```

One benefit of the tool over the curl command is that you don't need to care about the broker parameters, as the tool will (try to) do the discovery for you.

Comment: okay ill try to do the same , I have to try it. If it works for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to manage an instance of Apache ActiveMQ Artemis.  For example, you can use:

- JMX via a GUI tool like JConsole or JVisualVM
- Web-based console
- REST via Jolokia
- Management messages (e.g. via core, JMS, AMQP, etc.)

However, you cannot simply delete files out from underneath the broker.